# Clear cache on update interface with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular

Good afternoon, I'm developing a project and it's already in kubernetes in gitlab, it's already in production. But every change I make and update the url, the user needs to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to show the changes, does anyone know any way to perform this cache cleaning every time a new version is uploaded in kubernetes or even every time the person refresh the page?

Comment: Which is it - angularJS or Angular2+?

Answer (score 0):

Use a task runner like [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) to compress, combine and version your JS files. That way, your changes will always be in a new file name and you won't run into the cache issue. (The browser may cache index.html, but that can be circumvented with the meta tags below)

Whenever I build my angularJS project for production, I first run `npm version patch` and then compile. The javascript files get consolidated and minified. In that process, I append the file name with the npm version and update my index.html file.

To that end, I separate out my static javascript file (that contains combined minified libraries that rarely change) and my constantly updated app javascript. In the end my app imports those 2 files, and because the static JS rarely changes, it gets cached and that's good.

In addtion, place these cache-busting meta tags in your index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```